# Cannot save record from Django Model

Tags: django, django-models

I am making a change to a record in a sqlite3 database using Django, and the save() function doesn't seem to work.

I am able to save changes using the graphical admin app however.

Here is the code to the specific model I'm trying to do the save in:

```
 def pickup(self,item):
        room_items = Item.objects.filter(roomID = self.room.id)
        items = [ri.item_name for ri in room_items]

        if item in items:
            i = Item.objects.filter(item_name = item)
            i[0].roomID = 0
            i[0].playerID = self.id
            i[0].save()
            return f'{self.name} picked up the {item} from {self.room}'
        else:
            return f"{item} is not in the room. can't pick it up."
```

the pickup function is in a class called `Player`.  I am updating an `Item` record.  Any solutions?

Here is the entire models file for those who want more context:

```
from django.db import models
import string,random

class Room(models.Model):
        ### Field Columns in Room Table ###
    room_name = models.CharField(max_length = 64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, default=f"No Room description'" )
    up = models.CharField(max_length = 64, default="")
    down = models.CharField(max_length = 64, default="")
    left = models.CharField(max_length = 64, default="")
    right = models.CharField(max_length = 64, default="")

    def items(self):
        items = Item.objects.filter(roomID = self.id)
        return [i.item_name for i in items]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.room_name

class Player(models.Model):
    # uuid = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    HP = models.IntegerField(default=10)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, default=f"Room {random.choice(string.ascii_letters)}")#attempting to generate a random room name using ascii_letters from string library and random.choice()
    room = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    # inventory = models.ForeignKey(Inventory)

    def inventory(self):
        inventory = Item.objects.filter(playerID = self.room.id)
        return [i.item_name for i in inventory]

    def pickup(self,item):
        print(self.room.id)
        room_items = Item.objects.filter(roomID = self.room.id)
        items = [ri.item_name for ri in room_items]

        if item in items:
            i = Item.objects.filter(item_name = item)
            i[0].roomID = 0
            i[0].playerID = self.id
            i[0].save()
            i[0].persist()
            return f'{self.name} picked up the {item} from {self.room}'
        else:
            return f"{item} is not in the room. can't pick it up."

    def drop_item(self,item):
        pass

    def initialize(self,start):
        # start = input(f"{self.name}, you are outside the PyTower. It is a 10 story tower. There is a treasure chest on the top floor. Do you have what it takes to reach the top??? type 'y' to enter Pytower: ")

        if start == 'y':
            self.room = Room.objects.get(room_name = "Foyer")
            print(f"{self.name}, you have now entered the {self.room.room_name}")
            return f"{self.name}, you have now entered the {self.room.room_name}"
        else:
            print(f"{self.name}, when you're ready for Pytower, you may enter!")
            return f"{self.name}, when you're ready for Pytower, you may enter!"

        print(self.room.description)
        print('in room: ', self.room, 'up:',self.room.up, 'down:',self.room.down, 'left:',self.room.left, 'right:', self.room.right)
        return self.room

    def move(self,way=""):
        # print(self.room[way])  #causes error, Room object not subscriptable
        # print(way)
        # if self.room[way]:
        #     pass
        if way == 'up':
            if not self.room.up:
                print('you cannot go that way. no rooms there...')
                return 'you cannot go that way. no rooms there...'
            else:
                self.room = Room.objects.get(room_name = self.room.up)
                print('in room: ', self.room, 'up:',self.room.up, 'down:',self.room.down, 'left:',self.room.left, 'right:', self.room.right)
                return self.room

        elif way == 'down':
            if not self.room.down:
                print('you cannot go that way. no rooms there...')
                return 'you cannot go that way. no rooms there...'
            else:
                self.room = Room.objects.get(room_name = self.room.down)
                print('in room: ', self.room, 'up:',self.room.up, 'down:',self.room.down, 'left:',self.room.left, 'right:', self.room.right)
                return self.room

        elif way == 'left':
            if not self.room.left:
                print('you cannot go that way. no rooms there...')
                return 'you cannot go that way. no rooms there...'
            else:
                self.room = Room.objects.get(room_name = self.room.left)
                print('in room-', self.room, 'up-',self.room.up, 'down-',self.room.down, 'left-',self.room.left, 'right-', self.room.right)
                return self.room

        elif way == 'right':
            if not self.room.right:
                print('you cannot go that way. no rooms there...')
                return 'you cannot go that way. no rooms there...'
            else:
                self.room = Room.objects.get(room_name = self.room.right)
                print('in room: ', self.room, 'up:',self.room.up, 'down:',self.room.down, 'left:',self.room.left, 'right:', self.room.right)
                return self.room

        else:
            print('you have entered an invalid direction')
            return 'you have entered an invalid direction'

    def __str__(self):
        if not self.room:
            return  f"{self.name} is outside." 
        else:
            return f"{self.name} in {self.room}"

class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    strength = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=64,default="weapon")
    # playerID = models.ForeignKey(Player, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    # roomID = models.ForeignKey(Room, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    playerID = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    roomID = models.IntegerField(default=1,null=True,blank=True)

    def persist(self):
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.item_name
```

Comment: In what context is the `pickup` method being called?  Is this a view?

Comment: the pickup method is in the Player class in the models file.

Comment: Can you show both of your models please

Comment: @ReinstateMonica . I added the code for the entire model file above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand why your model isn't saving, you must first understand [how querysets are evaluated](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated).  Essentially, anytime you *iterate* over them, or [*slice*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation/509295#509295) them, they will hit the database, however there are caveats to this.

Consider the following abstract example:

```
def MyModel(models.Model):
    column = models.IntegerField()

>>> MyModel.objects.create(column=1)
<MyModel: MyModel object (1)>
>>> queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
```

**Slicing:**

```
>>> queryset[0].column = 2
>>> queryset[0].save()
>>> queryset[0].column
1
```

In the example above, I took a slice, **eg.** `queryset[0]`,  which hits the database, then immediately took ***a second slice***, to try and save the changes made, which hits the database a second time.  Finally, I took a third slice, which hits the database again.

Since the first slice **is not the same object** as the object I called `.save()` on, the changes are not reflected in the database.  To fix this, simply save a *reference* to the slice as a variable:

```
>>> instance = queryset[0]
>>> instance.column = 2
>>> instance.save()
>>> instance.column
2
```

In this example, I only hit the database twice: once when I call `instance = queryset[0]`, and a second time in `instance.save()`.

Here is the optimized version of your code:

```
def pickup(self, item_name):
    items = Item.objects.filter(item_name=item_name, roomID=self.room.id)

    if items:
        item = items[0]
        item.roomID = 0
        item.playerID = self.id
        item.save()
        return 'message'

    return 'no item'
```

Comment: You are awesome!  that worked.  I wonder why mine wasn't saving it in the database?

Comment: @AmirYunas I updated my answer with a detailed explanation, for why your changes weren't saving.